# unable to save into mongodb using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to save array of ids in the mongodb using node.js. I am getting error that bookmarks is null
//bookmarks.sites.push(element._id); element._id is from request.body.

There are more than 1 site Id's will be passed from the form in this form,
[{"_id":"5e88d1e5a9162a308dc55999"},{"_id":"5e88d1e5a9162a308dc55998"} ]

I am using forEach to iterarte through the above elements after confirming the User is valid.
This used will add the site id in the sites:[] array.

I am using foreach loop to iterate through and check if the site id does not exists then push element._id. but when I send the post request,

```
console.log('bookmarks 1 = ', bookmarks);
this statement prints bookamrks 1 =  null
```

**I want to know why it is printing null**

Thank you

```
const bookmarkSchema = new Schema( { user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }, sites: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Bookmark'}]
} );
post( cors.corsWithOptions, authenticate.verifyUser, ( req, res, next ) => {
    Bookmark.findOne( { user: req.user._id } ) //matching user._id from request returned fav document
        .then( bookmarks => {
            //console.log('req,user._id = ', req.user._id);
            //if (bookmarks) {
            req.body.forEach(
                element => {
                    console.log( 'bookmarks = ', bookmars );
                    console.log( 'element id outxidf T = ', element._id );
                    //console.log('req.body = ', req.body);

                    if (
                        //! tests for missing favorites
                        !bookmarks.sites.includes( element._id ) //from the request
                    )
                        console.log( 'element id = ', element._id );
                    //bookmarks.sites.push(element._id); */
                }

                //test for campsiteIDs in teh request body and check for existence in the Bookmark document
                //
            );
            console.log( 'bookmarkss = ', bookmarks );
            //bookmarks.save();
            //}//if
            //Bookmark.create(req.body);
        } ) //loop through fav documents
        //next thing in my loop I will test for campsiteObjectId from the body response.
        //.create(req.body)
        .then( s => {
            console.log( 'Favorites Created ', favorites );
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
            res.json( bookmarks );
        } )
        .catch( err => next( err ) );
} )
```

Comment: Hi there. Why is the log for bookmarks printing null? Perhaps, there is no bookmark with a user matching the user._id specified in the request.

Comment: Then I think the code should go inside the if block and print the console.log statement which is not printed.

Comment: Which`if` block is that? Also, I can't find the specific log you mentioned in the question `console.log('bookmarks 1 = ', bookmarks)` in the snippet you shared.